# running sum based on 2 column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to get a running sum calculation. I have the following table:

```
Date    State   Product    Total Sold or Returns    Transaction
22-Apr  FL       shoes            72                    Sale
22-Apr  FL      sandals            3                    Sale
22-Apr  TX       shoes             12                   Sale
22-Apr  TX       sandals           5                    Sale
23-Apr  FL      shoes              1                    Sale
23-Apr  FL      sandals            48                   Sale
23-Apr  TX      shoes               5                   Sale
23-Apr  TX      sandals            23                   Sale
22-Apr  FL      shoes              -65                  Returns
22-Apr  FL     sandals              -4                 Returns
22-Apr  TX      shoes              -25                 Returns
22-Apr  TX     sandals             -8                  Returns
23-Apr  FL     shoes              -2                   Returns
23-Apr  FL     sandals            -51                  Returns
23-Apr  TX     shoes               -5                   Returns
23-Apr  TX     sandals             -3                   Returns
```

I am trying to calculate the running total month to date of each product for each state. For example, for FL, shoes will be (72+(-65)) = 7 for 4/22 and then 7 +  (1+(-2))=6. Same for sandals, and also for TX.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with a cumulative sum window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(total_sold_or_returns) over (partition by state, product, year(date), month(date)
                                        order by date) as cumulative_sum
from t;
```

The `partition by` is taking the `state` and `product` -- and the month as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment yet but, one thing to point out is that to get the running total using a windowing function you use ORDER BY in the PARTITION. This only works in 2012 +. I know you said you were using 2014, but if you didn't know how ORDER BY works in the PARTITION, you wouldn't really understand the previous answer.